# Downloading Entire Azure Blob File Storage to a Local HDD

Tags: azure, azure-cli

I currently need to download all the files from these 2 file shares within azure blob storage to a local HDD, both file shares in total have 400GB enter image description here

[Example of where](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4TqHK.png)

the file structure between both of the shares are just a bunch of files and no folder directories.

I'm trying to use azure CLI to download the files like this

az storage file download 
--account-name "fileshare" 
--account-key "key" 
--share-name "email" 
--path "email/*" 
--dest "H:/"
but it throws an error saying invalid path.

any ideas where I am going wrong , or alternative options on how to download an entire fileshare easily to local HDD.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The most easiest way to manager Azure Storage is the tool called [Azure Storage Explorer](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/). All documentation is found [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows#prerequisites).

You can easily download all files from a File Share.

[image: Azure Storage Explorer]